# How can I get each value of array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I get an endpoint which take some products of the database.

That's endpoint brings a JSON which looks like this:

```json
idProduct   
  0 => "21"
colour  
  0 => "Red"
  1 => "Green"
size    
  0 => "M"
  1 => "XS"
```

So, I need to make a table which shows `colour[0]` with `size[0]`, `colour[1]` with `size[1]`, etc.

The main problem is that I can't access by the name of the column (size and colour), because in another case, the name can be ability, might, darkness, etc.

I tried this but doesn't works.

```php
echo '<tbody>';
foreach ($array_from_json as $key => $value) {
  for ($i=0; $i <= count($value) ; $i++) { 
    echo "<tr><td>".$value[$i]."</td></tr>";
  }
}
echo '</tbody>';
```

The array ($array_from_json) shows this in a var_dump:

`array(3) { ["idProducto"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "9" } ["color"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(4) "Azul" [1]=> string(5) "Verde" } ["talla"]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "L" [1]=> string(2) "XL" } }`

The JSON raw is:
`{"idProducto":["9"],"color":["Azul","Verde"],"talla":["L","XL"]}`

Comment: Why you use `for` into `foreach` ??? instead print directly `value` no?

Comment: `$value$` is an array too... So I need to iterate over it yet

Comment: you can use `foreach` again instead.

Comment: You will need to be more specific about the actual format of that data structure you receive. Is it true that all columns except the first always have the same number of entries. And is it generally true that all keys of those entries are the binding indicator between all those entries?

Comment: Please also add the raw json value you receive back.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini We'll get the same problem. If I do foreach two times, I get literally: `9AzulVerdeLXL`
So, How can I write the `<tr>` and `<td>` tags to display it in a table?

Comment: Offtopic tip: I'd suggest you to build a new array first with the required format, then put it to HTML, it will avoid at least one level of complication. As I can see all you need in this case is matching, colours with sizes, so you should iterate only one subarray and fetch matching pair from other, and put them into new array.

Comment: @biesior How would you pose that in code?

Comment: `$newArr = []; foreach ($array_from_json['colour'] as $key -> $value) { $newArr[] = [ ($array_from_json['colour'][$key], ($array_from_json['size'][$key] ]; } ; var_dump($newArray)`. That's pseudo code written from mobile, but should work, execute it ad check if it gives you result array as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

You can get the column names using `array_keys` function, you have to delete the first column name "idProducto" (because you don't want to iterate over it). This code will work regardless of the column names you choose.

Input data (json):

```
$json = '{"idProducto":["9"],"color":["Azul","Verde"],"talla":["L","XL"]}';
```

Php code:

```
$product = json_decode($json, true); //Convert a Json string to array

$keys = array_keys($product); //Get arrays keys

array_shift($keys); //Delete first key "idProducto"

echo '<table>';

for($i = 0; $i < count($product[$keys[0]]); $i++) {
    
    echo '<tr>';
    
    foreach($keys as $key) {        
        echo '<td>' . $product[$key][$i] . '</td>';
    }
    
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Output (without table head, but you can add with a foreach at the beginning):

| color | talla |
| --- | --- |
| Azul | L |
| Verde | XL |